# Hooking OpenProcess() or ReadVirtualMemory() in win32 userland code

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, dll

Is there anyway to hook/detour either of `OpenProcess()` or `ReadProcessMemory()` function calls to my own custom functions?

Without:

1. kernel driver on Zw/NtOpenProcess, requires rootkit exploit or
   driver signing for deployment
2. injecting .dll's in every process, spammy waste of resources and
   alerts many antivirus

I am trying to prevent other processes from getting a `HANDLE` or reading the memory of a vector of PIDs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do not hook the calls globaly on kernelmode, you have to get into every targetprocess. A dll would be the easiest solution, but you could do more hacky and tedious stuff.

Use OpenProcess and ReadProcessMemory (what a coincidence!) and WriteProcessMemory to modify every target process. Hook the desired functions and patch in your desired functionality with a filter function.

Note that if somebody gets to know what you are doing and wants to prevent it there is nothing you can do. He could re-patch your code or use some direct asm calls to call the APIs (SYSCALL).